# How to position "Selection Box" with ItemContainerStyle of a ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I've been reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates) documentation and I was wondering if it's possible to position the selection check box of the container? Specifically, this thing here:

[image: ListView]

Ideally, I want it aligned on the right. So far I've tried to use

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="WHAT DO I WRITE HERE?">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

With various *TargetTypes*. Is it even possible to position that Selection-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest you're looking in the wrong place. The `ItemContainerStyle` is adjust the `margin` `padding` and such properties of the container of the items of a `listview`.

What You need is a `style` for a `ListViewItem`. Lucky for us it's easily available from the [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) from the `MSDN Documentation`.

I won't paste the whole code here since, it's huge and it's cause deviated focus from the actual code that you need to tweak.

---

From the style from the above link, pick the second style of the two mentioned and refer to the below code:

```
<Border x:Name="MultiSelectSquare"
            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Width="20"
            Height="20"
            Margin="12,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Visibility="Collapsed" >
      <Border.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,20,20">
          <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectClipTransform"/>
          </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
        </RectangleGeometry>
      </Border.Clip>
      <Border.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform"/>
      </Border.RenderTransform>
      <FontIcon x:Name="MultiSelectCheck"
                FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                Glyph="&#xE73E;"
                FontSize="16"
                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Opacity="0"/>
    </Border>
```

The above code handles the `checkbox` kinda `tick mark with border` for `SelectionMode="Multiple"`.

> All the changes you want to do must be done in this style and the above code section of the style.

**Please Note:** I would advise not to play around with `Visibility` and `Opacity` property as they are modified using `VisualStates`. Don't worry about them they'll change states at runtime.